# How to do logging in azure functions and api management

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to create logging for API and azure functions.

As thinking to use, "service bus" to create logging.

Logging needs for each request, response and error.

Would it be correct approach to do logging for api management and azure functions through service Bus. and appreciate if any example to create service bus and call from azure or api management to log the requests/responses.

Note: Regarding Application Insights, as found its hit the performance and its more for performance monitoring then logging. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apimanagement/2018/01/12/application-insights-integration/

Answer (score 3):

I would still use Application Insight for that. You want to track requests and errors which Applicatin Insight will offer out of the box and also provides you a query language to query your logs or to build dashboards. Regarding your performance concern, you should just test the impact on your system - it most likely isn't that relevant.